# Flink source for periodical update

Tags: scala, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to implement external config for long-running flink job. My idea is to create custom source that periodically (every 5 minutes) polls JSON-encoded config from external service by http.

How to create source that perform action every N minutes?
How can I rebroadcast this config to all executors?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

first, you need to make an event class which will define all the attributes that your event stream has and then makes all getters, setters and other methods. An example of this class will be

```
 public class qrsIntervalStreamEvent {

    public Integer Sensor_id;
    public long time;
    public Integer qrsInterval;


    public qrsIntervalStreamEvent(Integer sensor_id, long time, Integer qrsInterval) {
        Sensor_id = sensor_id;
        this.time = time;
        this.qrsInterval = qrsInterval;
    }


    public Integer getSensor_id() {
        return Sensor_id;
    }

    public void setSensor_id(Integer sensor_id) {
        Sensor_id = sensor_id;
    }

    public long getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(long time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    public Integer getQrsInterval() {
        return qrsInterval;
    }

    public void setQrsInterval(Integer qrsInterval) {
        this.qrsInterval = qrsInterval;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o) {
        if (this == o) return true;
        if (!(o instanceof qrsIntervalStreamEvent)) return false;

        qrsIntervalStreamEvent that = (qrsIntervalStreamEvent) o;

        if (getTime() != that.getTime()) return false;
        if (getSensor_id() != null ? !getSensor_id().equals(that.getSensor_id()) : that.getSensor_id() != null)
            return false;
        return getQrsInterval() != null ? getQrsInterval().equals(that.getQrsInterval()) : that.getQrsInterval() == null;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int result = getSensor_id() != null ? getSensor_id().hashCode() : 0;
        result = 31 * result + (int) (getTime() ^ (getTime() >>> 32));
        result = 31 * result + (getQrsInterval() != null ? getQrsInterval().hashCode() : 0);
        return result;
    }


    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "StreamEvent{" +
                "Sensor_id=" + Sensor_id +
                ", time=" + time +
                ", qrsInterval=" + qrsInterval +
                '}';
    }


} //class
```

Now let's say you want to send these events at x events/ 5 seconds then you can write code something like this

```
public class Qrs_interval_Gen extends RichParallelSourceFunction<qrsIntervalStreamEvent> {
@Override
public void run(SourceContext<qrsIntervalStreamEvent> sourceContext) throws Exception {


    int qrsInterval;
    int Sensor_id;
    long currentTime;
    Random random = new Random();

    Integer InputRate = 10;

    Integer Sleeptime = 1000 * 5 / InputRate  ;


    for(int i = 0 ; i <= 100000 ; i++){


        // int randomNum = rand.nextInt((max - min) + 1) + min;
        Sensor_id =  1;

        qrsInterval =  10 + random.nextInt((20-10)+ 1);
       // currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        currentTime = i;

        //System.out.println("qrsInterval = " + qrsInterval + ", Sensor_id = "+ Sensor_id );
        try {
            Thread.sleep(Sleeptime);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }


        qrsIntervalStreamEvent stream = new qrsIntervalStreamEvent(Sensor_id,currentTime,qrsInterval);

            sourceContext.collect(stream);

    } // for loop


}

    @Override
    public void cancel() {

    }
}
```

Here whole logic is done by

if you want to send x events/ second then your sleep time will be inverse of that. For example to send 10 events/second

> Sleeptime = 1000 / 10 = 100 milli-seconds

Similarly, for sending 10 events/ 5 seconds, the sleep time will be

> Sleeptime = 1000 * 5 / 10 = 500 milli-seconds

Hope it helps, let me know if you have any questions